# System.Printing not found( C# )?

Tags: c#, dll, printing

I am trying to run the following example from MSDN:

```
using System.Printing;

public class PrintTest {
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create the printer server and print queue objects
    LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
    PrintQueue defaultPrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();

    // Call AddJob
    PrintSystemJobInfo myPrintJob = defaultPrintQueue.AddJob();

    // Write a Byte buffer to the JobStream and close the stream
    Stream myStream = myPrintJob.JobStream;
    Byte[] myByteBuffer = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes("This is a test string for the print job stream.");
    myStream.Write(myByteBuffer, 0, myByteBuffer.Length);
    myStream.Close();
    }
}
```

but the compiler is complaining

> The type or namespace Printing does not exist in the namespace
>   System(are you missing an assembly reference) ?

How do I solve this issue ?

> **EDIT**: How do I add a reference for command line compiled application ( Not Visual Studio)

Comment: "are you missing an assembly reference?"  Yes, you are.  You can guess its name.

Comment: Right click on "References" and add "System.Printing" namespace. I think this this will be available .NET Framework 3.0 onwards.

Comment: How do I do this for command line compiled application( No Visual Studio, I am using Notepad++ and Csc compiler ) ?

Comment: @quickCoder Download Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio Community which are free versions of Visual Studio. In your case I would choose Community.

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson My current development environment is a bit limited in what I can download so I am trying to make do with the command prompt.

Answer (score 8):

From the command line something like `csc /reference:lib\System.Printing.dll`

---

Original Answer

Project > Add Reference, then under 'Assemblies > Framework'.

Choose System.Printing.

You can find out which Assembly you need to add a reference to by Googling the namespace followed by the word 'assembly'. In your case:

`System.Printing assembly`

The second result is from MSDN and indicates which assembly System.Printing can be found in.

---

Comment: the command line option does'nt work. Anyone know the working version?

Answer (score 6):

**From Command prompt**
Create a public reference

```
/reference:[alias=]filename
/reference:filename
```

Where

> Arguments
>
> ---
>
> filename
> The name of a file that contains an assembly manifest. To import more than one file, include a separate /reference option for each file.
>
> alias
> A valid C# identifier that will represent a root namespace that will contain all namespaces in the assembly.

[Microsoft documentation page for cmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx)

**From Visual Studio Community 2013** (Free version)
Right click References folder in your solution and browse for it there.
[image: Step 1 how to add assembly reference]
[image: Step 2 how to add assembly reference]

Answer (score 1):

I could not find System.Printing to add as a reference. That was because it is part of WPF, and I tried to use it in a class library project.

I had to add `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` to the project, then I could use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an assembly reference. Add a reference to System.Printing.dll.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `System.Printing` assembly to your project.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0Abo17N.png]

You can find this by right clicking on your project and clicking "Add Reference". (You can search for it in the `Assemblies > Framework` tab)

Additionally, you must add `using System.IO;` in order to use `Stream`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Solution Explorer right click on References click on Add Reference click on the .NET tab and scroll to System.Drawing. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer found here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0648fdc4-f67b-476e-b434-998efec14b89/class-systemprintingprintcapabilities-not-found?forum=wpf

However, you'll need to add the Assembly called `ReachFramework`